# How to connect S3 to pyspark on local (org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3")

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

SPark version =3.2.1

Hadoop version=3.3.1

I  have followed all posts on StackOverflow, but couldn't get It to run. I am new to spark and trying to read json file.

On my local mac, I have installed homebrew and installed pyspark. I have just downloaded jars,  Do I need to keep somewhere?

```
Jars downloaded are : hadoop-aws-3.3.1
                       aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.172
```

I have kept this under /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/jars

```
 # /opt/python/latest/bin/pip3 list
import os

import pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
access_id = "A*"
access_key = "C*"

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import *

## set Spark properties
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1')

sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark=SparkSession(sc)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", access_id)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", access_key)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
df=spark.read.json("s3://pt/raw/Deal_20220114.json")

df.show()
```

Error:

```
 org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"
```

How am i running in local?

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1 test.py
```

Error :

```
 org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1(DataSource.scala:747)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:745)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:577)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:405)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

22/03/06 19:31:36 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
22/03/06 19:31:36 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://adityakxc5zmd6m.attlocal.net:4041
22/03/06 19:31:36 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
22/03/06 19:31:36 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
22/03/06 19:31:36 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
22/03/06 19:31:36 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
22/03/06 19:31:36 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
22/03/06 19:31:37 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
22/03/06 19:31:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/03/06 19:31:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/7q/r0xvmq6n4p55r6d8nx9gmd7c0000gr/T/spark-1e346a99-5d6f-498d-9bc4-ce8a3f951718
22/03/06 19:31:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/7q/r0xvmq6n4p55r6d8nx9gmd7c0000gr/T/spark-f2727124-4f4b-4ee3-a8c0-607e207a3a98/pyspark-b96bf92a-84e8-409e-b9df-48f303c57b70
22/03/06 19:31:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/7q/r0xvmq6n4p55r6d8nx9gmd7c0000gr/T/spark-f2727124-4f4b-4ee3-a8c0-607e207a3a98
```

Comment: You probably have to try with s3a connector instead of deprecated s3/s3n connector https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-S3A-filesystem-client-from-HDP-to-access-S3/ta-p/246316

Comment: Thank you, In that Aws.conf . I don't have /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop/ this path?  what should I do? .But I am able to run pyspark .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No FileSystem for scheme "s3"

You've not configured `fs.s3.impl`, so Spark doesn't know what to do with filepaths starting with `s3://`

Using, `fs.s3a.impl` [is recommended instead](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html), and you access files with **`s3a://`**

Comment: Actually , I dont have S3n or S3a. I have only S3 , in that case what should I change to?

Comment: What do you mean? Your question clearly shows you've set the `impl` property to s3n, so just change the filepath protocol to use that instead of s3

Comment: I have changed it to s3a, same error

Comment: You cannot just change one thing. For example, the class would need to be `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem` rather than `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem` like in your question.

Comment: Can you please see the code now, I have updated it

Comment: Again, change the `spark.read.json` line to use the correct protocol... `s3a://` now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242704/discussion-between-xi12-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: @Xi The file path is the exact same. Just change the first 3 characters before the colon. That's it

Comment: Do I need to change it to S3a every time?

Comment: Yes. Unless you want to define `fs.s3.impl` instead